# ten plus year old

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

> A: "my daughter gave it to me, now my daughter is 20 year old"
> C:"when your daughter gave it to you"
> A: "few years back"
> C: "Oh, when she was at ten plus year old"

Is "Oh, when she was at ten plus year old" grammatical and idiomatic?

Comment: The short answer is "No, it is not grammatical or idiomatic", but you didn't tell us what you want to mean, so it's very hard to give you more of an answer than that.

Answer (score 1):

It is all rather odd and non-idiomatic.

Why does A mention his daughter's age?  It seems irrelevant (should be "20 years old").

C's question is wrong "When did your daughter give it to you?"

A's response should be "A few years back."  That is vague (which is okay)  It probably means 3-5 years ago, but it could mean 8 or 12 years ago.

So C can't really conclude that the daughter must have been more than 10.  That is just an assumption, and should probably be marked with a question mark (C is asking for confirmation).  Given the general vagueness, C might as well assume that the daughter was more than 12...

This means you can use the common word "teenager"

> C Oh, when she was a teenager?

"at ten plus years old" is not idiomatic.  English doesn't have a common term for someone who is between 10 and 20,  But it does have a common term for someone between 12 and 20, and that is close enough.

Answer (score 1):

2 things are grammatically incorrect.

First, let's look at the grammar of "Oh, when she was at ten plus year old.'"

This phrase is not used (not idiomatic). If you want to say someone's age that is over 1 year old, then you say **'years'**.
If you want to say 10+1 years, then that is 11. So you would say, "When she was ten years old."
English speakers also don't use "at ____ years old" unless it's at the beginning of a sentence.

Additionally, the C part:

> "when your daughter gave it to you"

Add **'did'** before 'your.' Add **give** "When did your daughter **give** it to you?"

Because it is a question, you need to add *did*. In questions, you need to have a version of be (is, are, did, was, were) near or at the beginning of the sentence. Without it, it sounds like a statement.